# What is the best practice to name this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In our small team (5 human) we have problem naming **this**.
Some of us writes _this,some _self,some self,some instance,some i (short for instance)

```
let _this = this
let _i = this
let _instance = this
let self = this
```

Comment: There is no best practice. Come up with a naming convention that your team all agrees with, and then follow it.

Comment: @TravisJ: It's not required that they all agree. Naming is like curls-style: it doesn't matter that everyone agrees, just that everyone follows one style.

Comment: `let _THIS_IS_WHAT_WE_AGREED_ON_ = this`  Be as explicit as possible :)

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Consensus is best practice.

Comment: All of them are just as useful as `var number`. I'd either (1) use arrow functions to keep the context I need, or (2) name it after the value stored under this e.g.: `const startButton = this;`

Comment: @TravisJ: sure, but not always worth the effort when there are multiple strongly held opinions on something that in the end doesn't matter.

Comment: I would not recommend `let _i = this`. The name `i` is typically used for array indexes or iterators, and in all other cases, if a variable is used more than a couple of lines away from where it's declared, you should really avoid using single-letter names.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - In other words, "it depends". Sure, there will always be those times where it is more effort than its worth. In general, I would presume a large majority of the time teams are invested in working together as a group and would prefer a consensus to use as opposed to having everyone code to their own specs. If not, maybe some team building is in order. I hear Hawaii is nice this time of year.

Comment: Naming conventions for me so far
const  NAME_OF_CONSTANT
let my_variable( i only use let in for loops and such  because i only need it temporarily)
var SteadyMyHand or var theVariableName .

Comment: @p.s.w.g good point. i,j,k etc are obviously bad practice.Got answer,thanks all